# Eclipse RAP Dialog::open() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, web, eclipse-rap

I use Eclipse RAP to realize a web application. The following code throws a `NullPointerException` during execution of the selection `listener`:

```java
Link link = new Link(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
link.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
link.setText("<a>Dokument erfassen</a>");
link.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

        TestDialog dia = new TestDialog(getShell(),
                    SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dia.open(new DialogCallback() {
            public void dialogClosed(int returnCode) {
                System.out.println("Stored file: ");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

[image]

The code of the class TestDialog Looks like the following:

```java
public class TestDialog extends Dialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestDialog(Shell parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public TestDialog(Shell parent, int style) {
        super(parent,style);
    }
}
```

If I use the `MessageBox` class instead of the class `TestDialog`, everything works fine.

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

the RAP 3.1 implementation for the Dialog.open method uses shell.open(), but I can't find where variable shell is actually set to a value? Should this not be "parent" ?

```
 public void open( final DialogCallback dialogCallback ) {
    prepareOpen();
    returnCode = SWT.CANCEL;
    shell.open();
    shell.addShellListener( new ShellAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void shellClosed( ShellEvent event ) {
        if( dialogCallback != null ) {
          dialogCallback.dialogClosed( returnCode );
        }
      }
    } );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `Dialog` needs to override `prepareOpen()` which does nothing by default.

After returning from `prepareOpen()` the Shell that represents the dialog should be created and assigned to the `shell` field.

For example:

```java
shell = new Shell( parent, SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL );
shell.setText( getText() );
// create controls in shell
```

See the `FontDialog` for a more complete example: https://github.com/eclipse/rap/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.rwt/src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FontDialog.java